# How can a random variable have random variance?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

This seems counter-intuitive to me since variance is a difference of expectations and afaik, [unconditional expectation is a real number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223953/is-the-expected-value-of-a-random-variable-always-constant#comment2489632_1223953).

[Apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306620/ex-n1-mid-x-n-ex-n1-mid-mathscrf-n#comment2654007_1306865), $X_t$ where $dX_t = Y_t dW_t$, where $Y_t$ is an independent Brownian motion to $W_t$, has random variance.

Solving the SDE gives $X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t Y_s dW_s$

Computing the first and second moments give:

$E[X_t] = E[X_0] + E[\int_0^t Y_s dW_s]$

$E[X_t^2] = E[X_0^2] + 2E[X_0 \int_0^t Y_s dW_s] + E[\int_0^t Y_s^2 ds]$ by Itō isometry

$ = E[X_0^2] + 2E[X_0 \int_0^t Y_s dW_s] + \int_0^t E[Y_s^2] ds$ by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions)

I'm guessing that $E[\int_0^t Y_s dW_s]$ or $E[X_0 \int_0^t Y_s dW_s]$ is random? Why? It seems that $\int_0^t Y_s dW_s$ is a random variable with a unique mean given by $E[\int_0^t Y_s dW_s]$.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: The expectations listed above cannot be random. Conditional expectations could be random. Your description (as is) does not contain conditional expectations.

Comment: @zoli Is [muaddib](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306620/ex-n1-mid-x-n-ex-n1-mid-mathscrf-n#comment2654007_1306865) wrong?

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing as a random variance or expectation (at least in this context). A variance of a random variable is *always* a constant.

Comment: @saz How did muaddib have a random variable with random variance? I understand in the context of Bayesian inference or statistics, random variables can have random mean or variance, but in math? I can't imagine such

Comment: @BCLC Ask him/her. The only possible explanation I can think of is the following: Suppose the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ is a product space, i.e. $\Omega = \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ and $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}_1 \otimes \mathbb{P}_2$. Then, if $X$ is a random variable on $\Omega$, one could call $$\int X(\omega_1,\omega_2) \, d\mathbb{P}_1(\omega) = \mathbb{E}_1(X(\cdot,\omega_2))$$ a random expectation. Basically, the point is here that $X$ depends on multiple parameters and we only take the expectation with respect to one parameter, not both of them.

Comment: (However, I've never seen anyone use this kind of terminoloy in probability theory.)

Comment: @BCLC - I spent some time trying to figure out the root of the confusion and it comes down to me introducing the idea of random variance.  It is a non-standard term tossed around sometimes in Math Finance and doesn't have a proper definition.

Comment: (But what saz suggested it could be defined as is pretty on target).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Brownian motions, but I think the problem is basically the same as in the case of individual random variables as in [muaddib's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1306865): "Take the process $X$ where $X_0$, $X_1$ are iid positive random variables and $X_2$ is a normal random variable with variance $X_0+X_1$ and mean zero." Here $X_2$ could be said to have "random variance", namely in the sense that the conditional variance $\operatorname{Var}[X_2\mid X_0+X_1]=X_0+X_1$ is a random variable, which could be expressed as "the variance of $X_2$ depends on the value of $X_0+X_1$". Nevertheless, you are of course right that $X_2$ is a standard random variable with a standard non-random variance, which according to the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) is given by

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X_2]&=E_{X_0+X_1}(\operatorname{Var}[X_2\mid X_0+X_1])+\operatorname{Var}_{X_0+X_1}[E(X_2\mid X_0+X_1)]\\
&=E_{X_0+X_1}(X_0+X_1)+\operatorname{Var}_{X_0+X_1}\cdot\,0\\
&=E(X_0+X_1)\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Had a feeling it was conditional. Thanks.